# TypeError: reduce_sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep_dims' in TF 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I update my code to use Tensorflow 2.0 from earlier version.
while compiling model it throws error :

> TypeError: reduce_sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep_dims'

Do i need to make any specific changes for this in my code?

Answer (score 2):

It is `keepdims`, **not** `keep_dims`. See https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum

Comment: I did not use keep_dims... its the error that is from tensorflow library itself

Comment: Yeah I think is was changed from "keep_dims" to "keepdims" since the upgrade from Tensorflow 1 to Tensorflow 2. Here is a discussion about the topic: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6815